# How to UPDATE table data = ? WHERE id = ? in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, where-clause, placeholder

This is the error i'm getting:

RuntimeError: fewer placeholders (?) than values ('Joe', '7', '21', '6')

It is confirmed that the values Joe, 7, 21, 6 are passed through from my html form to python so it is some syntax error i believe.

I am trying to update a birthday entry in a database using the birthday id. I am able to run this query in SQLITE where I just type in the actual values instead of the qmark placeholders, so I am assuming its a syntax error in python. I've read the sqlite documentation and can't find any examples talking about UPDATE table data = ? WHERE id = ?

I can run other db query that are close to this in python without an error

This is what I would expect to work in python but it isnt..
I've tried every other syntactical variation of this I can think of as well

```
db.execute("UPDATE birthdays name = '?', month = '?', day = '?' WHERE id = '?'", name, month, day, id)
```

Because when I run the SQLITE query like this it works..

```
UPDATE birthdays name = 'Joe', month = '7', day = '21' WHERE id = 6;
```

Comment: Originally your code didn't have single-quotes around the placeholders.  Now it does.  Why did you make that change?  I imagine that makes them *strings* instead of *placeholders*.

Comment: Remove the quotes around the questionmarks. With the quotes, it inserts the `?` literally and the lib won't find any placeholders

Comment: I forgot to type the quotes initially so I added them. That would be an error without them but thats not the solution to the error of fewer placeholders () than values (...)

Comment: Ok I removed the quotes and now I get RuntimeError: near "name": syntax error

Comment: `UPDATE birthdays SET name = .....`

Comment: Thanks Mark, that was what i was missing

Answer (score 1):

Try without the ' around the placeholder. Placeholders on https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html don't have any quotes around them even for string values.

```
db.execute("UPDATE birthdays SET name = ?, month = ?, day = ? WHERE id = ?", name, month, day, id)
```

Comment: I just realized that I havn't been using quotes on my other queries, I just got carried away trying everything syntatically that I could to solve the problem.

Comment: For example another query that works in my program is this:  
            db.execute("INSERT INTO birthdays (name, month, day) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", name, month, day)

Comment: I updated it, you were also missing the SET keywork.